# GCP: Datalab Notebooks - Source Repository

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

The default Repository for the Notebooks within the Google Datalabs is datalab-notebooks. Is it possible to change this to another Repository?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I believe datalab is just using git under the hood to connect to Google Cloud Source Repository.  You should be able to change to a different repository by changing the "origin" location for that git installation (you can find steps on how to do this in the git documentation).

Fyi, GCP now offers [AI Platform Notebooks](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform-notebooks/) (made by the same team which made Datalab).  This will set you up with a generic git installation on your notebook and you can connect it to whichever repository you prefer